# When using AWS SQS, is there any reason to prefer using GetQueueUrl to building a queue url from the region, account id, and name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have an application that uses a single SQS queue.

For the sake of flexibility I would like to configure the application using the queue name, SQS region, and AWS account id (as well as the normal AWS credentials and so forth), rather than giving a full queue url.

Does it make any sense to use `GetQueueUrl` to retrieve a url for the queue when I can just build it with something like the following (in ruby):

```
region = ENV['SQS_REGION'] # 'us-west-2'
account_id = ENV['SQS_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID'] # '773083218405'
queue_name = ENV['SQS_QUEUE_NAME'] # 'test3'
queue_url = "https://sqs.#{region}.amazonaws.com/#{account_id}/#{queue_name}
# => https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/773083218405/test3
```

Possible reasons that it might not:

- Amazon might change their url format.
- Others???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you have any guarantee that the URL will have such a form. The official documentation states the `GetQueueUrl` call as the official method for obtaining queue urls. So while constructing it using the method above may be a very good guess, it may also fail at any time because Amazon can change the URL scheme (e.g. for new queues).

Comment: Saying that it could fail at any time isn't quite accurate.  Amazon won't break existing clients for already released WSDL versions.

Comment: Yes, I meant for new queues.

Comment: new queues != new clients.   Amazon knows there are existing applications which create new queues and that changing the queue URL will break them.

Comment: The documentation no longer says that the URL shouldn't be constructed. This probably means that it's fine to construct or hardcode the URL.

Comment: @KrzysztofCzelusniak I think it's also been that way. My default, however, would be that if the format is not explicitly specified in the API specs, we shouldn't assume its structure just basing on the examples and current usage. I think issuing a `GetQueueUrl` is the safer thing to do, which takes in to account possible future changes in SQS.

Comment: @adamw The format is explicitly specified in the documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-queue-message-identifiers.html#queue-name-url

`GetQueueUrl` is probably safer, but we saw that it added up to 200 ms of delay in sending messages, so if performance is critical, it's not really worth it.

Comment: @KrzysztofCzelusniak I would say that it's an example, but I agree that the format probably won't ever change ;) Still, what I would do it lookup the queue url once on startup and then use it during the application's life. Or once you know that the queue is created, you can just add its URL to a config file.

Comment: @adamw, It doesn't look like an example, it's quite direct. Sure, it could be cached, but what if it changed in between caching it and using it? Whether or not it's stored in a config file or in SSM or set as a constant is a bit irrelevant. It'd be adding superfluous logic for something that should never change. YAGNI. `GetQueueUrl` is the easiest solution, but introduces a performance hit. The next easiest solution is just hard-coding it, whether it's in a config file or whatever. Anything else is gold plating, which has a cost of its own in extra code that needs to be tested and maintained.

Comment: @KrzysztofCzelusniak as I think was mentioned before, I wouldn't expect the URL to change for existing queues. I just wouldn't hardcode the URL structure if it doesn't have to be, but of course approaches differ :)

Answer (score 2):

If Amazon changes the queue URL in a breaking way it will not be immediate and will be deprecated slowly, and will take effect moving up a version (i.e. when you upgrade your SDK).

While the documentation doesn't guarantee it, Amazon knows that it would be a massively breaking change for thousands of customers.

Furthermore, lots of customers use hard coded queue URLs which they get from the console, so those customers would not get the updated queue URL format either.

In the end, you will be safe either way.  If you have LOTs of queues, then you will be better off formatting them yourself.  If you have a small number of queues, then it shouldn't make much difference either way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe for safety purposes the best way to get the URL is through the `sqs.queue.named` method. What you can do is memoize the queues by name to avoid multiple calls, something like that:

```
# https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken/blob/master/lib/shoryuken/client.rb
class Client
  @@queues = {}

  class << self
    def queues(queue)
      @@queues[queue.to_s] ||= sqs.queues.named(queue)
    end
  end
end
```